# Javascript image.onload() guarantees image is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am working on an HTML5 game which uses a lot of images.
However, sometimes the game does not load properly and throws some error messages that suggest that some images have not been loaded correctly.
I use a preloading function, incrementing a variable before starting to set the src of an image and decrementing it in the onload() function. Only when this variable reached 0, i start drawing. Still sometimes I (and other users) see errors and the game doesnt load. Most of the time it works though.
Now I wonder... technically this should not be possible. Does the call of the onload function guaratee the image is loaded ? Because I feel it doesnt.

Here the code although I dont think it matters:

```
var ressourcesToLoad = 1;

// all the loadImage() calls
// ...

ressourceLoaded();


function ressourceLoaded()
{
    ressourcesToLoad--;

    // if(ressourcesToLoad == 0) start main loop
}


function loadImage(imgFile)
{
    ressourcesToLoad++;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = ressourceLoaded();
    img.src = imgFile;
    return img;
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `loadImage` function?

Comment: Still sometimes I (and other users) see errors and the game doesnt load - what are these errors? can you give a url or a fiddle or your game

Comment: @putvande its in the 3rd commented line

Comment: Can you try using $(window).load(function() ? Here all resources are loaded and you can start your game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the [`complete`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp) property tells you more accurate if the image has finished loading. Unfortunately there is no event that will be triggered when loading is done. One way could be to poll this property until it is set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, BUT as far as I remember:

1 In some browsers it can fire twice in a row for the same image

2 In some browsers it doesn't fire when image is loaded from cache

3 I'm not sure if it fires when server returns 404 for the image

And probably you should start loading next image only after loading previous. If you have a  lot of big images on the same domain and start them loading simultaneously, the "two connections per page" rule can break something for you.

P.S.: By some "some browsers" I mean "some browsers or their outdated versions".

Comment: What's wrong with loading them in parallel, what does break? It would be significantly faster, since it's more a 4/6/8/16-connections-per-server rule in modern browsers.

Comment: Well, you definetely can do this if you are sure that your visitor uses "modern browsers". I just warned that the issues may occur. P.S.: I'm not "missing" HTML5 part, I'm just answering about image.onload() in general. P.P.S.: However, poor internet connection or 200 images with 5Mb size can be enough to take all the 4/6/8/16 connections (and "timeout-kill" all others).

Comment: You mean old browsers got timeouts if they loaded too many resources over too few connections? Interesting, I didn't knew that.

Comment: I say "queuing". If you try to start 32 connections at the same time only the first 4/6/8/16 will be opened. Until one of them is closed other stay in queue and can timeout before even handshake. It occurs e.g. when you use too much XMLHTTP requests at the same time.